# Handle CSS element for particular item

Tags: jquery, css, cordova

I have so many images of same class. Want to change a particular image from that css class without affecting other elements.
Like: I have class "a" with a background image and this class is used for so many images. I only want to change a particular image after clicking on it.

Description: Actually I am implementing like status functionality so I want to change that like image on click event without affecting others like status image.
I got stuck here. I am using Phonegap jQuery Mobile.

```
 $(document).on("click", ".yvtw-like-btn", function(e) {
   debugger;
    e.stopPropagation();
    var jAnc = $(this);

    if (jAnc.attr('data-status-id')) {

        yumpod_service.showWaitLoader("Liking status...");

        var userHash = yumpod_service.playerDict["userHash"];
        $.when(send_request("likestatus", null,
                {"userHash": userHash, "statusid": jAnc.attr('data-status-id')}
            )
        ).done(function(data) {
                console.log("status_like success", arguments);

                try {
                    data = parseJson(data);

                    if (data && data["data"] && data["data"]["status"] === "sucess") {

                        yumpod_model.set("timeline", [data["data"]["user_status"]], "status_id");
                        yumpod_service.triggerEvent("loadTimeline_status");

                    }
                } catch (e) {
                    console.log("status_like error", e);
                }
                yumpod_service.hideWaitLoader();

                //yumpod_service.triggerEvent("loadGames",data);
            }).fail(function(error) {
                console.log("status_like fail", arguments);
                yumpod_service.hideWaitLoader();
            });
    }
    return false;
});
```

this is my jquery code.
I do not have enough point so cant upload image.
I have uploaded my code too.So please do not advice any childish way.

```
<a href="#" class="yvtw-like-btn ui-link" data-status-like="undefined" data-status-id="744"></a>
```

this is my 'this'  object.So haw can i change background image of a class using this keyword.

Comment: Impossible to answer in full without an example of your markup.

Comment: Can please provide of the code where you are trying to implement this.

Comment: @davidkonrad please do let me know.What else you want to answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** for styling custom element.

```
img[src~="url-of-image"] {
     custom style
}
```

Comment: Good suggestion. I would have referred to MDN though :) -> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Answer (score 0):

if you have many element with the same class and you want to make the effect on the clicked element you can use $(this) selector like this

```
$('.classname').click(function(){
     $(this).css('color','red');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way is:

```
$(document).on("click", "img.class", function(){
     var image = $(this);
    /* Do with this image what you whant */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always use the `$(this)` selector..

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
    $('.a').on('click',function(){
       $(this).css('color','blue');
    });
});
```

Comment: I already used it but not getting that attribute in this object